# swagger-ui docker image: Help understanding why query parameter using deepObject and explode does not result in the desired query

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I'm trying to define OpenAPI for a query parameter that uses a simple type for a deepObject.

According to the OpenAPI spec, the following should work:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: OpenAPI definition
  version: 0.0.1
paths:
  /example:
    get:
      parameters:
        - name: foo
          in: query
          required: false
          schema:
            type: object
            minProperties: 1
            style: deepObject
            explode: true
            example: >
              {
                "bar": "baz"
              }
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
        "400":
          description: Bad request
        "401":
          description: Authorization info missing or invalid
        "403":
          description: Unauthorized
        "404":
          description: Not found
```

Should result in a query such as http://localhost:9080/example?foo[bar]=baz if you use the same input as the given example. However, what I'm getting is http://localhost:9080/example?bar=baz. I've searched around and quadruple checked my syntax to make sure I am doing what I think is being described around the web, but it still doesn't result in the output I think the OpenAPI spec is describing. I feel like I must be doing something wrong and am just not seeing it. Can anyone identify what I am doing wrong?

Note, I also posted this question to the discussion on the [swagger-ui GitHub project](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/discussions/8250).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `style` and `explode` outside the `schema`, to the parameter level:

```yaml
      parameters:
        - name: foo
          in: query
          required: false
          style: deepObject  # <-------
          explode: true      # <-------
          schema:
            type: object
            ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I had a feeling it had to be something really simple, but I wasn't seeing it.